# Provinding link of an enterprise iPhone app to a website so that company employees can download app from this website link?

Tags: iphone

Can some one tell me the complete procedure of how we can provide a link of an enterprise iPhone app on to the web site.
Thanks any small help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You devices have to be provisioned for that.  Apple has many guides. http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/resources/